# Disable modules per environment / settings.php?

Tags: 8

Is there a way to disable certain modules on different environments from settings.php or another means in Drupal 8?

For example, if I am not on prod, I don't want XML Sitemap enabled.

Comment: This is pretty much covered by the dupe but it could do with some new answers so I stuck a bounty on it

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it pop up.